# Swift 3: How can we connect Database using PHP in Swift and fetch data in UITableView

Tags: php, sql, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to build an app that connects to the database using PHP. When my app starts, it connects to database and fetches all the records in a tableView. Each cells have some records, and when a cell is pressed, it passes to the second ViewController and fetches all the data that is related to first ViewController Cell.

Being checking this out for a long time but cant find.

Thanks for your time and effort :)

My code so far look like this :-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data_request("http://MY_URL/FILE.PHP")
    }



    func data_request(_ url:String)
    {
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let paramString = "data=test"
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            {
                print(dataString)
            }
        }

        task.resume()

    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly are the errors? Are you getting a response?

Comment: @LukeChase  I am getting the response in the output box. I am not getting an error neither I can fetch the records on the storyboard. Hope you understanding me.

Comment: Okay so you are getting a response, is it not the response you where expecting?

Comment: I get the results I am looking for in the output panel however, I cant get the data fetched on the tableview

Comment: Okay that is quite a broad question. I suggest you take a look at some tutorials for UITableviews. Here is one to get you started https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/